# How to use AsciiDoctorJ in Gradle to convert .adoc files to Markdown

Tags: gradle, markdown, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm currently replacing my Markdown files of my Java project with .adoc to get a seamless documentation across all modules, and I want to build a README.md out of it, preferable with the Gradle plugin and most likely during the CI build.

**How would I need to configure asciidoctor and which extension/plugin would be required to convert .adoc to .md?**

Edit: I think my question is obsolete, as Gitlab as well as GitHub support displaying README.adoc files directly, but I'll leave it here in case sb else has the same requirement for other reasons

Answer (score 0):

I agree, your question is a bit obsolete.

Asciidoc is more capable than Markdown, meaning that an Asciidoc->Markdown transformation can be lossy. You'd have to implement your own solution(s) when problems occur.

[`pandoc`](https://pandoc.org/) provides transformations for X->Y formats, but then you might have to rework the resulting Markdown.

It might be more productive to develop an Asciidoctor backend, where you provide the output implementation for all nodes in the "compiled" AST. AFAIK, there is no such backend currently available.